# Azure Webapp (using Nodejs) logging to Blob storage

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Azure Webapp (Windows) to host a nodejs app. Inside my app, I'm using bunyan as my logger library.

I have configured App logging to Azure Storage Blog through the web portal. I selected the storage accounts, blob container, etc.

If I go to Log Stream, I do see the logs from my app in the portal. However, those logs are not being stored in the selected Blob container. There's a folder (inside the container) that was created by the app service and it does log things like when a new version of my app is deployed using a CSV file but that's all.

I've read my posts indicating that Nodejs is not supported for this environment (logging to blob storage). Is this true? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For node.js websites the way to write application logs is by writing to the console using `console.log('message')` and `console.error('message')` which goes to Information/Error level log entries. **Currently only supported target for the nodejs log files is the file system**.

It looks as though you can't use blob storage for application logs in Azure Web Apps. However Azure blob storage adapters for popular nodejs loggers such as `winston`: [winston-azure-blob-transport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-azure-blob-transport).

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me to the documentation where it states that nodejs logs cannot be targeted to blob storage?

Comment: You could refer to this [article](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/#.XOtKSYgzaUm) and this [one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2018/08/03/debugging-node-js-apps-on-azure-app-services/).

Comment: The first article is from 2014. The second one is poorly written (even the links referred by the site don't work). I had already found those two sites, but I haven't been able to get a more recent documentation site with information relevant the topic of this question. I don't know why MS says that they support all major platforms (including nodejs)... I guess the devil is in the details...

Comment: Unfortunately the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-windows) states "Currently only .NET application logs can be written to the blob storage. Java, PHP, Node.js, Python application logs can only be stored on the App Service file system (without code modifications to write logs to external storage).":